# Something is changing the OSX default shell to tcsh

Tags: macos, shell, malware, tcsh

On one of the mac machines I'm somewhat responsible for (Snow Leopard), something periodically changes the default login shell from bash to tcsh.

This seems like it's probably suspicious, but not necessarily so.

Has anyone heard of anything that will transparently do this without notifying the user? Is this a known malware sign?

Comment: Are you able to change it back? You could check the `crontab`s and call `launchctl list` to see if there's anything suspicious.